# Generate page cache based on customer level, not at customer group level

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

In Magento page cache will generate based on customer group.

But how to generate page cache by customer id?

Lets say category page test.html
So Magento will create like this
test.html-not-logged-in,test.html-customergroup1 ,test.html-customergroup2